# Find matrix of $T$ if $T:P_2(x) \to P_3(x)$ is given.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If $T:P_2(x) \to P_3(x)$ is such that $T(f(x))=f(x)+5\int_0^x f(t)dt$, then choosing $\{1,1+x,1-x^2\}$ and $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ as bases of $P_2(x)$ and $P_3(x)$ respectively, find the matrix of T.

Comment: Done! What else?

Comment: @Vincent Check your notes for the theorem that tells you how to calculate this matrix. It is likely that you have been given at least one example that illustrates the use of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above. There is a result that I would use here. It tells me that I need to find the image of each of the basis vectors under $T$ and express these images as coordinate vectors with respect to the given basis for the image space. These vectors will be the column vectors or the required matrix.

Comment: @Vincent It looks good.